# Upgrading dual map program from Google Maps apiV2 to apiV3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map API V2 script allowing two maps of different sizes and zoom levels to move together, when one map is panned the other also moves to maintain the same center point.  The smaller map has a Xhair in the center that returns to the center after it has been panned, the larger map has multiple markers.

I'm trying to upgrade the code to API V3, but the V3 maps aren't moving each other and the smaller map Xhair isn't functioning. Can someone please tell me what am I missing in the script upgrade from API V2 to API V3?

**V2 code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

  function createMarker(point) {
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
  }

  // ===== Setup The Maps =====

  // Display the main map, with some controls and set the initial location 
  var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
  map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
  map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(54.531283,-125.125537), 12);

  // Set up three markers on the main map

  createMarker(new GLatLng(54.207882,-125.661621));
  createMarker(new GLatLng(49.214790,-124.054399));
  createMarker(new GLatLng(49.053632,-122.352859));

  // create the crosshair icon, which will indicate where we are on the minimap
  // Lets not bother with a shadow
  var Icon = new GIcon();
  Icon.image = "xhair.png";
  Icon.iconSize = new GSize(21, 21);
  Icon.shadowSize = new GSize(0,0);
  Icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(11, 11);
  Icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(11, 11);
  Icon.infoShadowAnchor = new GPoint(11, 11);

  // Create the minimap
  var minimap = new GMap2(document.getElementById("minimap"));
  minimap.setCenter(new GLatLng(54.531283,-125.125537), 7);

  // Add the crosshair marker at the centre of the minimap and keep a reference to it

  var xhair = new GMarker(minimap.getCenter(), Icon);            
  minimap.addOverlay(xhair);


  // ====== Handle the Map movements ======

  // Variables that log whether we are currently causing the maps to be moved

  var map_moving = 0;
  var minimap_moving = 0;

  // This function handles what happens when the main map moves
  // If we arent moving it (i.e. if the user is moving it) move the minimap to match
  // and reposition the crosshair back to the centre
  function Move(){
    minimap_moving = true;
if (map_moving == false) {
  minimap.setCenter(map.getCenter());
  xhair.setPoint(map.getCenter());
  xhair.redraw(true);
}
minimap_moving = false;
  }
  // This function handles what happens when the mini map moves
  // If we arent moving it (i.e. if the user is moving it) move the main map to match
  // and reposition the crosshair back to the centre
  function MMove(){
    map_moving = true;
if (minimap_moving == false) {
  map.setCenter(minimap.getCenter());
  xhair.setPoint(minimap.getCenter());
  xhair.redraw(true);
}
map_moving = false;
  }

  // Listen for when the user moves either map
  GEvent.addListener(map, 'move', Move);
  GEvent.addListener(minimap, 'moveend', MMove);
}

// display a warning if the browser was not compatible
else {
  alert("Sorry, the Google Maps API is not compatible with this browser");
}
```

**Non-working V3 code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function createMarker(point) {
    map.addOverlay(new google.maps.Marker(point));
  }     

  // ===== Setup The Maps =====

  // Display the main map, with some controls and set the initial location function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.531283,-125.125537),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

 // Set up three markers on the main map

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(54.207882,-125.661621),
        map: map
  });
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.214790,-124.054399),
        map: map
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.053632,-122.352859),
        map: map
  });

  // create the crosshair icon, which will indicate where we are on the minimap
  // Lets not bother with a shadow
   var Icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage();
  Icon.image = "xhair.png";
  Icon.iconSize = new google.maps.Size(21, 21);
  Icon.shadowSize = new google.maps.Size(0,0);
  Icon.iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(11, 11);
  Icon.infoWindowAnchor = new google.maps.Point(11, 11);
  Icon.infoShadowAnchor = new google.maps.Point(11, 11);

  // Create the minimap  
  var minimap = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('minimap'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.531283,-125.125537),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });      

  // Add the crosshair marker at the centre of the minimap and keep a reference to it

  var xhair = new google.maps.Marker(minimap.getCenter(), Icon);

  minimap.addOverlay(xhair);      

  // ====== Handle the Map movements ======

  // Variables that log whether we are currently causing the maps to be moved

  var map_moving = 0;
  var minimap_moving = 0;

  // This function handles what happens when the main map moves
  // If we arent moving it (i.e. if the user is moving it) move the minimap to match
  // and reposition the crosshair back to the centre 
  function Move(){
    minimap_moving = true;
if (map_moving == false) {
  minimap.setCenter(map.getCenter());
  xhair.setPoint(map.getCenter());
  xhair.redraw(true);
}
minimap_moving = false; 
  }   
  // This function handles what happens when the mini map moves
  // If we arent moving it (i.e. if the user is moving it) move the main map to match
  // and reposition the crosshair back to the centre 
  function MMove(){
    map_moving = true;
if (minimap_moving == false) {
  map.setCenter(minimap.getCenter());
  xhair.setPoint(minimap.getCenter());
  xhair.redraw(true);
}
map_moving = false;
  }

  // Listen for when the user moves either map      
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'move', Move);
  google.maps.event.addListener(minimap, 'moveend', MMove);

// google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Have you see the [upgrade guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3)?  addOverlay, setPoint are v2; MarkerImage is deprecated v3.

Comment: where's your `initialize` function?

Comment: javascript is case-sensitive. `Center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.531283,-125.125537),` should be `center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.531283,-125.125537),`

Comment: Thanks: fixed the javascript case, the initialize function is at the end of the code. I have read and tried to follow the upgrade guide, sorry but I am really new at this and will try to figure out the addoverlay/setPoint/MarkerImage issues for the xhair. Still don't understand why the maps aren't moving together in V3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade guide seems to have little information on Events, some obsolete events don't seem to be listed in the obsolete code.  The V2 events: "move" and "moveend" are apparently not supported in V3, however there are similar (but not the same) V3 events; dragstart, drag, dragend, and center_changed.  Since the drag events aren't compatable with additional selection buttons I'm using: I went with center_changed which works like a charm for my application.

I explored a few options for the center cross hair, but they seemed to have dead spots or jumped around when the maps were panned, so I eliminated the javascript solutions and went with a simple solution from Drew Noakes.

This is what I came up with to fix the non-working V3 code, might help someone out there.

**V3 code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  // ===== Setup The Maps =====   
  // Display the main map and set the initial location
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.531283,-125.125537),
      zoom: 12,
      zoomControl: false,
      scaleControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

 // Set up the three markers on the main map 
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(54.207882,-125.661621),
        map: map
  });
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.214790,-124.054399),
        map: map
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.053632,-122.352859),
        map: map
  });     

  // Create the minimap  
   var minimap = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('minimap'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.531283,-125.125537),
      zoom: 7,
      zoomControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });         
  // Add the crosshair marker at the centre of the minimap using html and CSS 

  // ====== Handle the Map movements ======      
  // Variables that log whether we are currently causing the maps to be moved    
  var map_moving = 0;
  var minimap_moving = 0;

  // This function handles what happens when the main map moves
  // If we arent moving it (i.e. if the user is moving it) move the minimap to match
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function(){
    minimap_moving = true;
if (map_moving == false) {
  minimap.setCenter(map.getCenter());     
}
minimap_moving = false; 
  })      
  // This function handles what happens when the mini map moves
  // If we arent moving it (i.e. if the user is moving it) move the main map to match
   google.maps.event.addListener(minimap, 'center_changed', function(){
    map_moving = true;
if (minimap_moving == false) {
  map.setCenter(minimap.getCenter());     
}
map_moving = false;
  })  

// google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);    
</script>
```

//The HTML:

```
      <div id="map" style="width:627px; height: 627px"></div>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="minimap" style="width:370px; height:370px;"></div> 
        <div id="xhair"><img src="../images/xhair.png" width="20" height="20" /></div>
      </div>
```

//The CSS:

```
#container { position:relative; }
#map { height:100%; width:100%; }
#xhair {
position:absolute;
left:47%;
top:47%;    
}
```

Comment: You can view the working V3 map at: http://www.fishnbc.com/Locations/fishingspots.php